# Como eliminar warnings al documentar un servicio WebApi a través de HelpPage

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-web-api, visual-studio-2013

A través del **HelpPage** se documentan los servicios **ASP.Net WebApi** y se deben establecer los comentarios en cada modelo, método y controlador para que la documentación sea lo más precisa posible, sin embargo, cuando no existe comentario alguno en métodos y clases que no se tienen que documentar al cliente (*FilterConfig*, *RouteConfig*, *WebApiConfig*) me sale la siguiente advertencia o Warning

> *Missing XML comment for publicly visible type or member*

Sabiendo claramente que esto no implica riesgo en el código ni es un posible error o descuido de uso de una variable no asignada...., ¿cómo puedo obtener el famoso

> 0 Errores, 0 Warnings

sin tener que documentar absolutamente todo el código de mi solución y que sea claramente apreciable los *0 Warnings*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Una opción es deshabilitar las advertencias desde las propiedades del proyecto, en la pestaña Build.

Coloca los siguientes códigos: **1591,1572,1571,1573,1587,1570**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Obtuve la solución de aquí: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203863/missing-xml-comment-for-publicly-visible-type-or-member

Me cuentas si te funciona.

Comment: solo existe la opción de deshabitar esas advertencias ?